# UITableView Cell content not showing swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to display the title label onto my tableview cell but nothing appears when running. I also tried to put a standar label into the cell but it disappears when i run it.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage

struct postTry {
    let title : String!
}

class CarMakeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {
    var posts = [postTry]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount)

            for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                guard let value = rest.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> else { continue }

                guard let  title = value["Title"] as? String else { continue }

                let post = postTry(title: title)

                self.posts.append(post)
            }

            self.posts = self.posts.reversed();
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellMake")

        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(21) as! UILabel
        label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

        return cell!
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "makemodel" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destVC = segue.destination as! DetailNewsViewController
                destVC.titleText =  posts[indexPath.row].title

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a separate .xib file where you create a new table view cell that holds your cell and label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following first:
change your cellForRowAt method to this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellMake", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.text = post.title

    return cell
}
```

If you have set up your tableview correctly and you are sure you are receiving the objects from Firebase, this should work.

Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delegate your tableView onto your ViewController class

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self
```